# Fazer um slider com views(?)

Tags: slider

No fundo do site tenho uma chamada de view:

`<?php $this->load->view('frontend/'.$this->domain.'/services/box_crm'); ?>`

Ela é a descrição de um serviço:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
*Deixei o conteúdo fora de foco por questão de privacidade do cliente*.

Porém agora o cliente quer adicionar os seus outros serviços no mesmo local, com um slider, que ficaria mais ou menos assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Deixei o conteúdo fora de foco por questão de privacidade do cliente*.

**A pergunta**: Como posso fazer esse slider chamando as views ao invés de imagens? 
Quando clico para passar ele carrega a view seguinte, e assim por diante. É possível fazer isso?

Comment: Isso teria que ser feito do lado do cliente, e portanto não acho ser possível. Qual framework esta utilizando?

Comment: CodeIgniter. Eu já tenho todas as views prontas aqui, só preciso criar o slider com elas

Comment: Acredito que basta utilizar um slider que suporte HTML nos slides, como o jssor, e repetir este código de geração de view, um para cada view que deseja adicionar ao slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte maneira:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function simpleSlider(type){
            var sliderActive = $("#slider .sliderActive");
                if(type == 'prev') {
                    var sliderPrev   = sliderActive.prev().length ? sliderActive.prev() : $("#slider li:last");
                    sliderPrev.addClass('sliderActive').fadeIn();
                } else {
                    var sliderNext   = sliderActive.next().length ? sliderActive.next() : $("#slider li:first");
                    sliderNext.addClass('sliderActive').fadeIn();
                }
                sliderActive.removeClass('sliderActive').fadeOut();
            }
        $(function(){
            $("#slider li:first").fadeIn();

        });
    </script>

  <div class="buttons">
<a href="javascript:simpleSlider('prev')"><img src="assets/frontend/img/services/seta_esquerda.png"></a><a href="javascript:simpleSlider('next')"><img src="assets/frontend/img/services/seta_direita.png"></span></a>
</div>

<ul id="slider">
        <li class="sliderActive"><?php $this->load->view('frontend/'.$this->domain.'/services/box_crm'); ?></li>
        <li><?php $this->load->view('frontend/'.$this->domain.'/services/box_landing'); ?></li>
        <li><?php $this->load->view('frontend/'.$this->domain.'/services/box_seo'); ?></li>
        <li><?php $this->load->view('frontend/'.$this->domain.'/services/box_rastreator'); ?></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: acredito que você não erá passar nenhum parâmetro para view então aconselho usar `<?php include ""; ?>`

Comment: Obrigado pela dica! Mas utilizo o CodeIgniter, e ele tem esta função bem parecida com include. https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html

Comment: você está se referendo a `$this->load->file('filepath/filename', true/false)`? Pois eu utilizo ci e não conhecia essa função, obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Digo a função $this->load->view('name', $data, true/false) Veja aqui : https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html